# Why does this deadlock occur?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

We're using MySQL with the INNODB storage engine.
The `account` table is accessed by two different transactions. We didn't expect a deadlock because only one transaction is holding a lock (2):

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-05-12 11:04:51 7fa10bf3b700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 91255426, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 434044, OS thread handle 0x7fa14b33b700, query id 224359496 10.0.31.146 test_user statistics
SELECT netbalance, grossbalance INTO p_netbalance, p_grossbalance FROM account WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 12332 n bits 824 index `user_id` of table `test`.`account` trx id 91255426 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 212 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 00000000005e0c01; asc      ^  ;;
 1: len 8; hex 00000000035de4e3; asc      ]  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 91255425, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
13 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 9 row lock(s), undo log entries 4
MySQL thread id 434043, OS thread handle 0x7fa10bf3b700, query id 224359489 10.0.31.146 test_user update
INSERT INTO account (added, user_id, currency_code, netbalance, grossbalance, status) VALUES
                (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW.user_id, NEW.currency_code, NEW.netbalance, NEW.grossbalance, "ACTIVE")
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE netbalance = (netbalance + NEW.netamount), grossbalance = (grossbalance + NEW.grossamount + NEW.testfee)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 12332 n bits 824 index `user_id` of table `test`.`account` trx id 91255425 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 212 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 00000000005e0c01; asc      ^  ;;
 1: len 8; hex 00000000035de4e3; asc      ]  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 12332 n bits 824 index `user_id` of table `test`.`account` trx id 91255425 lock_mode X waiting                                      
Record lock, heap no 212 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 00000000005e0c01; asc      ^  ;;
 1: len 8; hex 00000000035de4e3; asc      ]  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

These transactions are two instances of the same trigger:

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER balance_update BEFORE INSERT ON regtransaction
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE p_netbalance   FLOAT(21, 4) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE p_grossbalance FLOAT(21, 4) DEFAULT NULL;

    IF (NEW.added AND ABS(NEW.added - NOW()) > 300.0) THEN
        SET p_check = 0;
    END IF;

    SELECT netbalance, grossbalance INTO p_netbalance, p_grossbalance FROM account WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;

    IF (p_netbalance IS NULL OR p_grossbalance IS NULL) THEN
        CALL test.calculateBalanceForUser(NEW.user_id, NEW.cro, p_netbalance, p_grossbalance);
    END IF;

    SET NEW.netbalance   = p_netbalance   + NEW.netamount;
    SET NEW.grossbalance = p_grossbalance + NEW.grossamount + NEW.testfee;

    INSERT INTO account (added, user_id, currency_code, netbalance, grossbalance, status) VALUES
        (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW.user_id, NEW.currency_code, NEW.netbalance, NEW.grossbalance, "ACTIVE")
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE netbalance = (netbalance + NEW.netamount), grossbalance = (grossbalance + NEW.grossamount + NEW.testfee);
END */;;
```

Comment: run `SHOW CREATE TABLE test.account` please

Comment: Both look like Triggers.  Let's see the trigger code, too.

Comment: Added the trigger code; we're trying to log more to find out what is the `account` row(s) the triggers are probably conflicting on.